# Маршруты не работают в продакшн

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу подключить freessl на сайт. Для этого мне надо пройти верификацию
Надо чтобы по этим путям были файлы

```
http://xxx.su/.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y
http://www.xxx.su/.well-known/acme-challenge/bpxL8socCbfycpgSuhWHnuscPKEKhKq9FMLUrzrwP6M
```

Скачал оба файла в папку `public`

Создал два маршрута

```
  get "/.well-known/acme-challenge/bpxL8socCbfycpgSuhWHnuscPKEKhKq9FMLUrzrwP6M" => redirect("bpxL8socCbfycpgSuhWHnuscPKEKhKq9FMLUrzrwP6M")
  get "/.well-known/acme-challenge/unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y" => redirect("unQnzG3-dT7Tsb1scTjsBfscrkQ3Da03cRSQOhXa06Y")
```

В **development**-среде когда я перехожу по ссылку - то успешно вижу содержимое файла
В **production**-среде он тупо скачивает файл, что не есть комильфо.

В production у меня связка `nginx+puma`. Может это как то связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `nginx.conf` добавить:

```
server {
  # Прочие настройки вашего сервера

  location /.well-known {
    root /var/www/html;
  }
}
```

Это даст nginx понять, что при любом `url` с `/.well-known` нужно отдавать файл из директории `/var/www/html`.

Далее вы именно в эту директорию (`/var/www/html/acme-challenge`) на сервере закачиваете ваши сертификаты. И они становятся доступны по приведенным вами `url`-адресам.

Comment: 404 Not Found
...

Comment: 2017/07/26 10:11:56 [error] 3641#3641: *1 "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.163.56.96, server: , request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.ru"