# Ошибка при установке LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt, vesta

При установке LetsEncrypt на домен, выходит ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
Challenge failed for domain bavistudio.ru
http-01 challenge for bavistudio.ru
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: bavistudio.ru
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://bavistudio.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/llupb_bHsai-yyzcXUPEUEv2Qp0fLKIMntqK5fC6-70
   [2a03:6f00:1::5c35:602e]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD
   HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

VestaCP, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: на запрос ` http://bavistudio.ru/.well-known/...` никто не подтвердил владение доменом

Comment: @nörbörnën А как можно подтвердить?

Comment: Давай вместе почитаем справочный раздел "Как задать хороший вопрос?": [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Давай место попробуем выполнить тщательный поиск ответа: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=well-known+%5Bnginx%5D) или [тыц2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=well-known). Что-нибудь подходит?

Comment: судя по обилию указанной информации, есть предположение, что автор вопроса думает, что обращается в техподдержку своего хостера.

Comment: Ничего не помогло

Comment: @Виталий https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697879/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%88%d0%bd/697884#697884